# Long lived JMS sessions. Is Keeping JMS connections / JMS sessions always opened a bad practice?

Tags: java, jms

Is keeping JMS connections / sessions / consumer always open a bad practice?

Code draft example:

```
// app startup code

ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory)jndiContext.lookup(CF_JNDI_NAME);
Connection connection = cf.createConnection(user,pass);
Session session = connection.createSession(true,Session.TRANSACTIONAL);
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(new Queue(queueName));
consumer.setMessageListener(new MyListener()); 
connection.start();
connection.setExceptionListener(new MyExceptionHandler()); // handle connection error


// ... Message are processed on MyListener asynchronously ...


// app shutdown code

consumer.close();
session.close();
connection.close();
```

Any suggestions to improve this pattern of JMS usage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a very common and acceptable practice when dealing with long lived connections.  For many JMS servers it is in fact preferable to creating a new connection each time it is needed.

Answer (score 9):

Agreed. Here are some [good tips on how to use JMS efficiently](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-jms-efficiently.html) which includes keeping around connections/sessions/producers/consumers.

You might also want to check the [recommendation on using transactions](http://activemq.apache.org/should-i-use-transactions.html) too if you are interested in maximising performance.

Answer (score 5):

The choice of keeping connection/session/producer/consumer open for long or not should be based on the frequency at which producer/consumer sends/receives messages.

If a producer sends or a consumer receives messages frequently then the connections/sessions/producer/consumer should be kept open. On the other hand if messages send/receive is infrequent then it is not good keeping these JMS objects open will consume system resources like sockets.

Answer (score 4):

In our app, we will have connections/sessions/consumers/producers open for months at a time. We've had to work with our vendor (BEA) to make that work reliably.  But any troubles with that is a bug the vendor needs to fix.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, there is no need to close the sessions, producers, and consumers of a closed connection( [javax.jms.Connection](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.fabric3.api/javax-jms/1.1.1/javax/jms/Connection.java?av=f#276) ).
The code below should be enough to release the resources:

```
try { 
        this.connection.close();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        //
    }
```