# Single queue: concurrent message processing with multiple consumers

Tags: jms

I am new to jms. The goal is to  process messages concurrently from a queue in an asynchronous listener's onMessage method  by attaching a listener instance to multiple consumer's with each consumer using its own session and running in a separate thread, that way the messages are passed on to the different consumers for concurrent processing.

1) Is it possible to process messages concurrently from a single queue by creating multiple consumers ?
2)  I came up with the below code, but would like to get your thoughts on whether the below code looks correct for what I want to accomplish.

```
public class QueueConsumer implements Runnable, MessageListener {

public static void main(String[] args) {




    QueueConsumer consumer1 = new QueueConsumer();
    QueueConsumer consumer2 = new QueueConsumer();
    try {
        consumer1.init("oms", "US.Q.CHECKOUT-ORDER.1.0.JSON");
        consumer2.init("oms","US.Q.CHECKOUT-ORDER.1.0.JSON");
    } catch (JMSException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }


    Thread newThread1 = new Thread(consumer1);
    Thread newThread2 = new Thread(consumer1);
    newThread1.start();
    newThread2.start();



}


private static String connectionFactoryName = null;
private static String queueName = null;


private static ConnectionFactory qcf = null;
private static Connection queueConnection = null;


private Session ses = null;
private Destination queue = null;
private MessageConsumer msgConsumer = null;

public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(QueueConsumer.class);

public QueueConsumer() {
    super();
}

public void onMessage(Message msg) {
    if (msg instanceof TextMessage) {
        try {

            //process message

        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

}

public void run() {

    try {
        queueConnection.start();
    } catch (JMSException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

        System.exit(-1);
    }
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}



public void init(String factoryName, String queue2) throws JMSException {
    try {

        qcf = new JMSConnectionFactory(factoryName);


        queueConnection = qcf.createConnection();


        ses = queueConnection.createSession(false,
                Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        queue = ses.createQueue(queue2);
        logger.info("Subscribing to destination: " + queue2);

        msgConsumer = ses.createConsumer(queue);


        msgConsumer.setMessageListener(this);

        System.out.println("Listening on queue " + queue2);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

}

private static void setConnectionFactoryName(String name) {
    connectionFactoryName = name;
}

private static String getQueueName() {
    return queueName;
}

private static void setQueueName(String name) {
    queueName = name;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes absolutely
2. I only took a brief look and I noticed that you pass the wrong consumer to your second thread:

   ```
   Thread newThread2 = new Thread(consumer1); // has to pass consumer2
   ```

   beside of this, some variables such as `ConnectionFactory` are static and initialized multiple times/overriden. You only need one connection that could create multiple sessions and/or consumers.

Comment: So, if I create the connectionfactory and connection in the main method itself once and then create the session, consumer, listener  once each for a consumer I guess that's what you are referring to?

Comment: Yes, you should also be able to share the session, related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741713/relationship-between-jms-connections-sessions-and-producers-consumers

Comment: since  the messages in a session are processed serially, if i create the consumers from the same session instance instead of different session instances, then the messages wont be processed concurrently right , only one of the consumers will get a message at a time since they belong to the same session instance?

Comment: @Dag Sharing JMS sessions is not safe; only connections and factories can be shared, everything else in the JMS world is not thread safe.

Comment: thanks for the responses. have modfied the code and have some questions posted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114995/jms-concurrently-processing-messages-from-a-tibco-queue   , whenever you guys have time please  give your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Related to the code example you provided, It is not recommanded by Oracle to create low-level threads on a deployed application. Example for Weblogic :
[Using Threads in WebLogic Server](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/topics.htm#WLPRG386)

Answer (score 0):

Instead in the applicationcontext.xml, where you have made the bean of mail container, you can add concurrent consumer property which would be a better approach.

```
<bean id="jmsMailContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
<property name="concurrentConsumers">
    <value>100</value>
</property>
<property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
<property name="destination" ref="mailDestination"/>
<property name="messageListener" ref="jmsMailConsumer"/>
```